# TypeError while running gulp. But can not find any TypeError is there any version issue of Node and npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

My Gulp file was running Good but when I update the Node 6 to 8 it was throwing an error. To solve that error I revert back to Node 6. But after that, It showing "TypeError dest.on is not a function" but I can't find any TypeError. Can anyone advise me what I've done wrong?
Node version: 6.11.4
npm version: 3.10.10
My gulpfile.js is given below

```
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var gulpAutoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var wait = require('gulp-wait');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var imagePngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var imageRecompress = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress');

var B_SCSS_PATH = 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss';
var B_JS_PATH = 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js';

var STYLE_PATH = 'public/css';
var JS_PATH = 'public/js';
var IMG_PATH = 'public/images';
var FONT_PATH = 'public/fonts';

gulp.task('styles', function(){
   console.log('Starting style task');
   return gulp.src('resources/scss/style.scss')
   .pipe(wait(500))
   .pipe(plumber(function(err){
      console.log('Styles Task Error');
      console.log(err);
      this.emit('end');
    }))
   .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
   .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
   }))
   .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
   .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()])
 //.pipe(minifycss())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(STYLE_PATH))
   .pipe(livereload());
});
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
   console.log('Starting Script task');
   return gulp.src('resources/js/**/*.js')
   .pipe(plumber(function(err){
    console.log('Styles Task Error');
    console.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
 }))
.pipe(concat('main.js'))
//.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest(JS_PATH))
.pipe(livereload());
});
gulp.task('BootstrapStyle', function(){
console.log('Starting Bootstrap Style task');
return gulp.src(B_SCSS_PATH + '/bootstrap.scss')
.pipe(plumber(function(err){
    console.log('Bootstrap Styles Task Error');
    console.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
 }))
.pipe(sass({
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
}))
.pipe(postcss([autoprefixer()])
.pipe(gulp.dest(STYLE_PATH))
.pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('BootstrapScripts', function(){
console.log('Starting Booststrap Script task');
return gulp.src(B_JS_PATH + '/bootstrap.js')
 .pipe(plumber(function(err){
    console.log('Styles Task Error');
    console.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
  }))
 .pipe(concat('bootstrap.js'))
 //.pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(JS_PATH))
 .pipe(livereload());
 });
gulp.task('images',function(){
console.log('Starting Image compression task');
return gulp.src('resources/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,svg,gif}')
    .pipe(imagemin(
            [
                imagemin.gifsicle(),
                imagemin.jpegtran(),
                imagemin.optipng(),
                imagemin.svgo(),
                imagePngquant(),
                imageRecompress()
            ]
    ))
.pipe(gulp.dest(IMG_PATH))
});

gulp.task('default',
 ['styles','scripts','BootstrapStyle','BootstrapScripts','images'], 
function(){
console.log('Default task running');
});


gulp.task('watch', ['default'], function(){
console.log('Watch task running');
require('./server.js');
livereload.listen();
gulp.watch('resources/scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']).on('change', 
   livereload.changed);
gulp.watch('resources/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']).on('change', 
  livereload.changed);
gulp.watch(B_SCSS_PATH + '/**/*.scss', ['BootstrapStyle']).on('change', 
  livereload.changed);
gulp.watch(B_JS_PATH + '/**/*.js', ['BootstrapScripts']).on('change', 
  livereload.changed);
gulp.watch(IMG_PATH, ['images']).on('change', livereload.changed);
gulp.watch('public/*.html').on('change', livereload.changed);
});
```

[Gulp Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NrFk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why anyone did not answer my question. But I solved my own problem. Hope it will help someone else. I've uninstalled and installed the node and reordered Gulp Style task as follows.

```
gulp.task('styles', function(){
  console.log('Starting style task');
  return gulp.src('resources/scss/style.scss')
  .pipe(wait(500))
  .pipe(plumber(function(err){
    console.log('Styles Task Error');
    console.log(err);
    this.emit('end');
  }))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass({
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
  }))
 .pipe( postcss([ autoprefixer()]) )
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(STYLE_PATH))
 .pipe(livereload());
});
```